# Compute the parents state based on the data of the child components: ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I am trying to implement a settings page where I have a global settings and some kind of child settings(in form of a slider).

I have the following scenarios:

1)When all of the child settings is on , then parents switch state should be turned on state

2)When any of the child settings is off, then parents switch state should be switched to pending

3)When all of the child settings is off, then parents switch state should be switched to off state

4) Also On click of button, I need to get the current state of all the child components.

Have tried the following approach but it does not seem like working. For this , I am using react-multi-toggle for this toggle switch.

I am able to get the state whenever the you do toggling inside, but it is not propagating to parent

Can someone help here ?

Code Sandbox Link : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-toggle-r5dpi

### App.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ChildSwitch from "./ChildSwitch";
import ParentSwitch from "./ParentSwitch";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      parentVal: "",
      switch1Val: "",
      switch2Val: "",
      switch3Val: ""
    };
  }

  onGetChildSwitchValues = () => {
    console.log(this.state);
  };

  setChildSwitchValue = value => {
    this.setState({ value });
  };

  setParentSwitchValue = value => {
    this.setState({ value });
  };

  render() {
    const { parentVal, switch1Val, switch2Val, switch3Val } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        Parent Switch :{" "}
        <ParentSwitch
          parentSwitch={parentVal}
          onSelect={this.setParentSwitchValue}
        />
        Child Switches :
        <ChildSwitch
          childSwitch={switch1Val}
          onSelect={this.setChildSwitchValue}
        />
        <ChildSwitch
          childSwitch={switch2Val}
          onSelect={this.setChildSwitchValue}
        />
        <ChildSwitch
          childSwitch={switch3Val}
          onSelect={this.setChildSwitchValue}
        />
        <button onClick={this.onGetChildSwitchValues}>Get Child Values</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

### Parent Switch

```
import MultiToggle from "react-multi-toggle";
import React from "react";
import "react-multi-toggle/style.css";

export default class ParentSwitch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      options: [
        {
          displayName: "Disabled",
          value: "disabled",
          optionClass: "red"
        },
        {
          displayName: "Pending",
          value: "pending",
          optionClass: "grey"
        },
        {
          displayName: "Enabled",
          value: "enabled",
          optionClass: "green"
        }
      ],
      selected: "pending"
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { options, selected } = this.state;
    return (
      <MultiToggle
        options={options}
        selectedOption={selected}
        onSelectOption={() => {}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

### ChildSwitch

```
import MultiToggle from "react-multi-toggle";
import React from "react";

export default class ChildSwitch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      options: [
        {
          displayName: "Disabled",
          value: "disabled",
          optionClass: "red"
        },
        {
          displayName: "Enabled",
          value: "enabled",
          optionClass: "green"
        }
      ],
      selected: "disabled"
    };
  }

  onSelectOption = selected =>
    this.setState({ selected }, () => {
      this.props.onSelect(this.state.selected);
    });

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.selected);
    const { options, selected } = this.state;
    return (
      <MultiToggle
        options={options}
        selectedOption={selected}
        onSelectOption={this.onSelectOption}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setChildSwitchValue = value => {
    this.setState({ value });
};
```

this adds {value: value} to the state and results in this state:

```
{parentVal: "", switch1Val: "", switch2Val: "", switch3Val: "", value: "enabled"}
```

Comment: Did you mean that the parent can't be toggled by clicing and it only reacts to the states of the children? this is that https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-toggle-pf0ou

Comment: You could add a name prop to the switches and use that as a key in the state, then add the name to the callback so you can set `(key, value) => {
    this.setState({ [key]: value })` , and there are no binds or  separate functions in the parent.

Comment: @thatthat,say i receive an object of this kind {switch1:"enabled",switch2:"disabled",switch3:"enabled" } from the server, would the child switches take this and sets it state automatically? Say within componentDidMount i get this object after an API call

Comment: In the sandbox above the parentSwitch state just depends on the 3 child switches. If all 3 are not equal then the parent is pending. If you set state to the App component it will give that state as props to its children, this could be in componentDidMount or anywhere else.

Comment: @thatthat,so you mean to say componentDidMount (after i get the above object after an Api call)inside App would set all States properly? and I'll be able to change the child switch States later on?

Comment: Right, sorry just noticed that children held their own state. You should just use the value int the childSwitch-prop. So just use the prop as the selectedOption. Definitely go with the sandbox in @niiapa s answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198059/discussion-between-thathat-and-vjr).

Answer (score 2):

I got you started with fixing your issue:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-toggle-5hvs1

The problems were... child information cannot propagate up to parent in React unless you have a single source of truth in your application either by using tools like Redux or just the local storage, which I don't advice.

So in that case, your child components need to be controlled ones. Parent should hold their state if they want to be aware of their children...

And from there you can do your comparisons for parent toggle all on or off or whatever.

Good luck.