# How do I listen for onclick on a set of radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement a system where the user can only select one button at a time.
So there are a set of colors 'Red, Blue, Black, etc'. If the user clicks on 'Red' label it should receive the class 'check'.
If the user decides they want 'Blue' label then the 'check' should be removed from 'Red' label to be on 'Blue' label now.

I cannot simply use the document.querySelectorAll().addEventListener() since this is react.
**For example in vanilla JS, I could easily do something like this:**

```js
const colorBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.color-radio-btn');
let checkedBtn = 0;
let checkedsizeBtn = 0;
let color;

colorBtns.forEach((item,i) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        colorBtns[checkedBtn].classList.remove('check');
        item.classList.add('check');
        checkedBtn = i;
        color = item.innerHTML;
    })
})
```

**And here is my react snippet:**

```js
const ShowProduct = () => {
  return(
    <div className='product-details'>
                  <input type="radio" name="color" value="Black" hidden id="black-color"/>
                  <label htmlFor="black-color" className="color-radio-btn">Black</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="color" value="Red" hidden id="red-color"/>
                  <label htmlFor="red-color" className="check color-radio-btn">Red</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="color" value="White" hidden id="white-color"/>
                  <label htmlFor="white-color" className="color-radio-btn">White</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="color" value="Yellow" hidden id="yellow-color"/>
                  <label htmlFor="yellow-color" className="color-radio-btn">Yellow</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="color" value="Green" hidden id="green-color"/>
                  <label htmlFor="green-color" className="color-radio-btn">Green</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="color" value="Purple" hidden id="purple-color"/>
                  <label htmlFor="purple-color" className="color-radio-btn">Purple</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="color" value="Purple" hidden id="blue-color"/>
                  <label htmlFor="blue-color" className="color-radio-btn">Blue</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="color" value="Purple" hidden id="orange-color"/>
                  <label htmlFor="orange-color" className="color-radio-btn">Orange</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="color" value="Custom" hidden id="custom-color"/>
                  <label htmlFor="custom-color" className="color-radio-btn">Custom</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="color" value="NotCustom" hidden id="not-custom-color"/>
                  <label htmlFor="not-custom-color" className="color-radio-btn">1-Color</label>
                
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<ShowProduct />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.product-details .color-radio-btn,
.product-details .size-radio-btn{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 1px solid #383838;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-left: 0;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #383838;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.product-details .color-radio-btn.check,
.product-details .size-radio-btn.check{
    background: #383838;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57520564/dynamically-add-classes-for-list-of-radio-button-based-on-its-state-reactjs

Comment: @buzz its definitely something that works but I'm looking for a way that I can just loop through all of the labels and mark which one is checked without doing so much copy/pasting the handler into the labels itself.
Although I'm not sure if thats possible. I'll update the question to add a block of vanilla JS for example.

Comment: React has it's own equivalent of listeners, mixing an matching can cause problems. Tread carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is reactJs. So you can do this using state manipulation... You should take a event handler for onclick.. then you will update the class check using value from state.like below

```
state:{
    selectedColor:'Red'
}

onClickHandler=(event)=>{
    this.setState({selectedColor:event.target.value});
}
```

and html like this..

```
<input type="radio" checked={this.state.selectedColor==='Black'} name="color" value="Black" hidden id="black-color" onClick={this.onClickHandler}/>
<label htmlFor="black-color" className={"color-radio-btn"+(this.state.selectedColor==='Black'?' check':'')}>Black</label>

<input type="radio" checked={this.state.selectedColor==='Red'} name="color" value="Red" hidden id="red-color"/>
<label htmlFor="red-color" className={"color-radio-btn"+(this.state.selectedColor==='Red'?' check':'')} onClick={this.onClickHandler}>Red</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, this will definitely work, but what I'm looking for or "wondering" if its possible for me to just loop through all labels. Without repeating the onClickHandler.
But I'm not sure if that would be too complex. Check my update I made that includes the vanilla JS example. Let me know if its something possible perhaps.

Comment: This seems to be more efficient, I've tried looking into other resources but this out of all seems to be the best. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a strong chance you can solve this with CSS only:

```
.product-details input:checked + label{
    background: #383838;
    color: #fff;
}
```

This will style the [`label` following](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) a [checked element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) contained in the `.product-details` element.